# Get document's fields has more than N elements

Tags: solr

In SOLR I have documents has fields like below;

```
"geolocation": [
          "40.154400,-75.279900",
          "40.117416,-75.119203",
          "40.23931,-75.23126",
          "40.18417,-75.07946"
        ]
```

I would like to get documents have `geolocation` field has more than 3 items, such as above.

How can I write this filter in solr?

I am looking something like;

> len(geolocation) >= 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upon indexing, just add the length of that field to another, custom field, then query the later one. There are several ways you can do this:

1. prepare the new field value on the client side
2. using the built in [CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html). The example in the docs does exactly what you want